# avoid entering dll while debugging, use it like in production

Tags: c#, debugging, dll, webforms, obfuscation

I have inherited a C#/WebForms project which uses a "magic" dll. For the dll I don't have the sources and it seems obfuscated somehow. Moreover, if I start debugging in Visual Studio, I get an FatalExecutionEngineError at a very early stage, in Application_BeginRequest(). Important to mention is that the project together with the dll work fine in production. My problem is debugging. If I remove that dll and replace its classes and methods by some dummies, I don't get that error. I was thinking to debug in Visual Studio but somehow to use the dll like in production. Of course, I won't be able to debug the dll but, at least, I could debug the rest of the project.

So, how to do that? How to make the dll "think" is in production? A trivial solution like "Enable Just My Code" did not help. Can I configure somewhere the solution to exclude the dll from debugging? Can I do anything to avoid accessing the dll by the debugger?

Comment: Seems the DLL has some anti-debugging stuff baked in. Can you contact the author/vendor of the DLL?

Comment: Is that "magic" _so_ unique that this is the only dll available that gives you the desired functionality? Using the debugger is something that would make _me_ look for alternatives if one of my used dependencies prevented me from doing.

Comment: The answer might depend on the fact how does the dll know it's being debugged. And that's difficult w/o checking it in the dll.

Comment: @KlausGütter No, the author died.

Comment: @PawełŁukasik I was hoping that I can do something not to the dll but to the debugging environment, meaning Visual Studio.

Comment: @Gigi maybe, everything (I think) depends on the fact "how" the dll detects it